# Laptop with Ubuntu 19.04 sometimes does not come out of suspend. Only force power off works

Tags: suspend, 19.04

I have a Dell Latitude E7440, with Ubuntu 19.04. Usually it works great, but sometimes, when I put it suspend, it does not come out of it. No buttons work. I can only long press the power button to turn the laptop off then restart it.

Comment: Same here on a Samsung RC512.

Comment: Same with Dell Latitude 5590. I have that issue with 18.04 also. It's work fine for a long time, but months later (maybe after some updates) it starts hanging after suspend. Not always, but sometimes. I've tried to install different kernels but had no success. Strange, but when I install 19.04 it was all ok for months. Same as with 18.04 I start having that issue after some update. I believe that if I reinstall fresh 19.04 the issue will gone